# Tkinter Events in for loop

Tags: python, tkinter, event-handling

I am currently working on an app with tkinter, which is basically PHPMyadmin.
After the login I want to display all the databases in Labels and attach an Event to them. Well it kinda worked...

Currently this code just prints out all the databases when clicked, but I want it to print just its own name. If it is possible, I don't want to create the events. Is there a way to "customize" Events?

```py
for x in mycursor:
    if x == "":
        ""
    else:
        y += ''.join(x) + ","
        def event(event):
            print(y)
    
        label = Label(dbframe, text=x)
        label.bind("<Button-1>", event)
        label.configure(font="Helvetica 10 bold")
        label.pack()
```

Comment: You should change the name of your call back function so that it does not shadow the name of your parameter.

Comment: you will have to bind function with argument `bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, name=x: yourfuntion(event, name))` and you get it in `def yourfunction(name): print(name)`

Comment: did you check what you get in variable `event`? It may gives access to `label` and it may gives you text from label `event.widget["text"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bind` sends `event` with information which widget was clicked and you can get text from `Label` using `event.widget["text"]`

---

Minimal working example:

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: all functions at the beginning

def my_function(event):
    print("widget:", event.widget['text'])

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

for name in ['Table A', 'Table B', 'Table C']:
    label = tk.Label(root, text=name)
    label.bind("<Button-1>", my_function)
    label.pack()
    
root.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to send to function other value then you can use `lambda` to bind function with value.

If you use `lambda` in loop then you need first assign this value to variable in lambda

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: all functions at the beginning

def my_function(event, text):
    #print("widget:", event.widget['text'])
    print("text  :", text)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

for name in ['Table A', 'Table B', 'Table C']:
    label = tk.Label(root, text=name)
    label.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, text=name:my_function(event, text))  # you have to use `text=name` when you use in `for`-loop
    label.pack()
    
root.mainloop()
```

Or you can assign value to label - ie. `label.own_value = "..."` and later get it as `event.widget.own_value`

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: all functions at the beginning

def my_function(event):
    #print('widget:", event.widget['text'])
    print("event :", event.widget.own_value)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

for name in ['Table A', 'Table B', 'Table C']:
    label = tk.Label(root, text=name)
    label.own_value = f"Hello {name}"
    label.bind("<Button-1>", my_function)
    label.pack()
    
root.mainloop()
```